# how to keep ngrok alive after mac mini goes to sleep

Tags: macos, ngrok

I setup ngrok on a mac mini so that it can act as a build machine for ios.  So when somebody merges in github it will trigger a webhook that will kick off a jenkins build on the mac mini.  However, when the machine goes to sleep and I try to navigate to the jenkins instance I get an error

```
Tunnel XXXXXXXX.ngrok.io not found
```

Is there something I need to do to keep the connection alive?

Comment: `caffeinate` maybe?

Comment: If the machine goes to sleep, the running programs (including ngrok) will be suspended. If you want to set the machine up for unattended access, check out [this Apple KB article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202824) and modify your Energy Saver settings to prevent the machine from sleeping entirely.

Comment: is it possible to lock it without suspending running programs?